# What is the sed comand to fix this file so second to last boolean is converted to opposite

Tags: text-processing

Give a file containing lines of text such as

```
"00007960-9d81-4192-b548-ad33d6b0ca54","true",0.984725773335,"false",1.0,"true",0.808817088604,"false",0.705779910088,"false",0.928222000599,"false",0.999984204769,"false",1.0,"false",0.904409646988,"true",0.979391694069,"true",0.977430343628,"false",0.999999582767
```

what is the sed (or similar) command to fix this file so the second to last boolean value on each line is replaced with the opposite value. So for some lines the value "false" will become "true", and for others the value "true" will become "false"

```
"00007960-9d81-4192-b548-ad33d6b0ca54","true",0.984725773335,"false",1.0,"true",0.808817088604,"false",0.705779910088,"false",0.928222000599,"false",0.999984204769,"false",1.0,"false",0.904409646988,"true",0.979391694069,"false",0.977430343628,"false",0.999999582767
```

(note the second to last true has become false)

Comment: Is that one line or three?

Comment: its just one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{a["\"true\""] = "\"false\""; a["\"false\""] = "\"true\""; OFS=","} {$(NF - 3) = a[$(NF - 3)]}1'
```

This assumes that the third last field of each record is a `"true"` or `"false"`.

The following tests if the third-last field is `"true"` or `"false"`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{a["\"true\""] = "\"false\""; a["\"false\""] = "\"true\""; OFS=","} $(NF -3) in a {$(NF - 3) = a[$(NF - 3)]}1'
```

Comment: Great ive tried it and tested it and it works great, never would have worked that answer out myself !

Comment: When thinking in terms of fields, awk is the natural command. A sed version might have been shorter, but a lot more complex.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
    while IFS=, read -r -a line; do 
       if [ "${line[@]:(-4):1}" = \"true\" ]; then 
           IFS=,; printf '%s\n' "${line[*]:0:$((${#line[@]}-4))},\"false\",${line[*]:(-3)}"
       else
           IFS=,; printf '%s\n' "${line[*]:0:$((${#line[@]}-4))},\"true\",${line[*]:(-3)}"
       fi
    done <file.txt
```

Here we are creating an array from each line with elements separated on `,`.

Then we are checking whether the 4th element from the end is `"true"` or `"false"` and then replacement is done accordingly.

Comment: Is the output also CSV? Use `IFS=,` and `[*]`.